# How to parse and get the last received value from a XmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, xmlhttprequest, server-sent-events

I have a web service that returns an SseEmiter, i am using it to program a loading bar but...Well, the method to receive it is this:

```
static async synchronize(component: Vue) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PATCH', 'myUrl.com');
    xhr.responseType = "text"
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'mySessionToken')
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
            resolve(xhr.response)
        } else {
                reject({status: this.status, statusText: xhr.statusText})
        }
    }
    xhr.onerror = function () {reject({status: this.status, statusText: xhr.statusText})}
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) { alert(xhr.responseText) }}
    xhr.onprogress = function(onEvent) {
    console.log(xhr.response)
    }
    xhr.send()  
}
```

Right now this works, but...The `xhr.response` data returns this as a string.

```
data:"{ hello: '1' }"
data:"{ hello: '2' }"
data:"{ hello: '3' }"
data:"{ hello: '4' }"
data:"{ hello: '5' }"
data:"{ hello: '6' }"
data:"{ hello: '7' }"
data:"{ hello: '8' }"
data:"{ hello: '9' }"
data:"{ hello: '10' }"
data:"{ hello: '11' }"
data:"{ hello: '12' }"
data:"{ hello: '13' }"
data:"{ hello: '14' }"
data:"{ hello: '15' }"
data:"{ hello: '16' }"
data:"{ hello: '17' }"
data:"{ hello: '18' }"
data:"{ hello: '19' }"

//And so on until it reach 100.
```

This doesn't seem like a problem, but what happens is that on each emitted event, the entire state history is returned, getting larger with each value:

[image]

In short, is there any way to get ONLY the last value of such response? `Json.parse()` is throwing errors, probably because the response is not formatted as json.

I could share some code of the web service where the SseEmitter comes from, but i don't think it's necessary to resolve this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: "...probably because the response is not formatted as json." Why not start by getting your response to be formatted correctly instead of trying to parse a malformed response?

Comment: It should, the server endpoint is producing their values as a `MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE`, which is marked as `application/stream+json`That's where the "probably" comes from, I'm not sure if it's a server issue or a client issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since the string is a JSON string you could parse that

```
const data = JSON.parse(xhr.response.replace("data:", "")) // { hello: 'xx' }
```

Comment: As said, this won't work because every data:"{ hello: 'xx' }" is received as a whole string.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. An ugly yet working solution would be to use string replace. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `XMLHttpRequest` to consume SSE, instead of `EventSource`?

Anyway, assuming you have a good reason, you need to do a bit more work.

First make a new function to get the latest data block; we will be giving this a JS object, not a string:

```
function onData(d){
console.log(d)
}
```

Then, the basic idea is to keep track of what we have processed so far, and just slice off the new bit:

```
let lastLen = 0

xhr.onprogress = function(onEvent) {
  const s = xhr.response.slice(lastLen+5)
  lastLen = xhr.response.length
  onData(JSON.parse(s))
}
```

If we did `xhr.response.slice(lastLen)` we just get just the last "data: {...}" block (possibly with leading and/or trailing whitespace), so the `+5` is to get us past the "data:" part.

This is rather brittle. If there is leading whitespace that `+5` will be wrong. You might also get two or more "data: {...}" blocks arrive together. In which case you need to do something like: `const parts = xhr.response.slice(lastLen).split("\n\n")` then process each entry in `parts`.

To do it properly you should study the EventSource standard, or the code of one of the polyfill libraries. Or simply use one of those polyfill libraries ;-)